# loading and replacing the image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have low resolution image which is loaded first,once it is loaded i need to replace it with a high resolution image.

I try to do so in html img tag but in throws error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you post some code? (use the {} button in the editor to mark the code lines)

Comment: @Soner - thanks! Need to get some more votes to get that changed

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace the image try using

```
$('#Image').find('img').attr('src', ['/ImagePath/', NewImageName].join(''));
```

Or may be you can consider changing just the src

```
$('#Image').attr('src', '/ImagePath/NewImageName');
```

Comment: Using `find` in this case is completely unnecessary - why not just use `$('#Image img')` - assuming you know somehow that this is the correct selector?

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript only:**

```
document.getElementById('idOfYourImg').src = '/new/path.png';
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#idOfYourImg').attr('src', '/new/path.png');
```